# How to implement Trapezoidal Integration with Infinite Limits in C?

Tags: c, integration, infinity

I am trying to create a c program to integrate sin(x)/sqrt(x) between 0 and Infinity. I am using the trapezium rule by cutting off the end points as the function tends to infinity.

However the total returned is too high and I am not sure why. Here's the code:

```
#include<math.h>
#include<stdio.h>

double func(double u)
{ double a;
  a = ((sin(u))/(sqrt(u)));
  return a;}

void main()
    {
    int i, N;
    double sum, u, a, b, h, Fa, Fb, F;

    printf("Enter value of N\n");
    scanf("%d" ,&N);

    a=0.01;
    b=1000;

    h=(b-a)/(N-1);

    sum=0;
    F=func(a);
    u=a;

    for(i=0; i<N; i++)
    {
            sum=sum+F;
            u=u+h;
            F=fabs(func(u));
    }

    Fa=func(a);
    Fb=func(b);

    sum=sum-(0.5*Fa)-(0.5*Fb);
    sum=sum*h;

    printf("I: %lf\n", sum);
}
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: What is the input, what is the expected and actual outputs?

Comment: Expected value: 1.2533

Comment: Input is the number of trapeziums to use, so the greater the input the closer to the intended result we should be

Comment: You are not checking the return value of `scanf()` so it might be happening that your code is invoking undefined behavior.

Comment: Bit weird that this has been posted - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29086951/integral-approximation

Comment: For input = 100, output = 38.5

Which appears to be from the for loop summation reaching too high a value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

working example: http://ideone.com/Xibrov

just remove the `fabs` in the line `F=fabs(func(u));`.

and you should use `int main(void)` and `return 0;` at the end instead of `void main()`.

Comment: Hi Mch,

N = 10000 in your example works!
But for N = 100 I get -0.31, is this just an error due to too low values for N?

Comment: You have to note that you integrate from 0.01 to 1000, not from 0 to infinity. This and the small N works together to create a wrong answer.

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is on the line

```
F=fabs(func(u));
```

What you actually want for integrating `func` is

```
F=func(u);
```

In this case I beleive the issue is that `fabs(func(u))` is not integrable at infinity, so your algorithm will diverge.

Comment: Hi Degustaf,

Removing fabs returns -0.31 for N=100.

Comment: @CreditChris That is not particularly surprising as the [Error](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trapezoidal_rule#Error_analysis) grows cubicly in `b-a` and decreases as a square in the number of steps.

Comment: @CreditChris Besides, you are using a trig function that has a period of 2\pi (about 6.283) and only sampling every 10.  You are going to miss most of the oscillations.  I would set `N=1000` at a bare minimum.